# Enemy AI in Unity2D

Tags: unity, 2d

How to make a enemy AI follow in Unity2D so that it can recognize paths, example jumping and ladder usage?

I want an enemy AI like Keystone Kapers game in Unity2D. If there is tutorial links please tell me.

Comment: Game AI is a very broad subject. There are lots and lots of approaches to it. Whole books were written about this topic. Unity unfortunately doesn't assist you a lot in it, especially in 2d games (in 3d games, you can at least use the Unity navigation mesh system). So you can and have to transfer the general principles of game AI to Unity.

Answer (score 1):

A good approach as always would be the A* Algorithm. Here are a few links that will help you (I advise you to read them in order) :

- [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm) : Basic understanding ;
- [Red Blob](https://www.redblobgames.com/pathfinding/a-star/introduction.html) : A really nice introduction that goes more in depth, using pseudo-code ;
- [J.Gallant](http://www.jgallant.com/nodal-pathfinding-in-unity-2d-with-a-in-non-grid-based-games/) : A Unity 2D approach, that generates a grid using raycast. He gives you the code. I re-implemented it so ask me if you need technical help.

You will need to tweek a little bit this algorithm to include ladders and jumps, maybe using different kinds of nodes : "Ladder", "JumpPossibility", "WalkingPath" etc. As the J.Gallant solution is based on Raycasts, it can be achieved using appropriate Colliders and Layers for the Ladders and other interaction objects.